# XML parsing performance

Tags: android, xml, parsing

**Simplexml** parse 3200 elements in 7 sec on Galaxy S. Every element has 7 attributes.
How I can to improve performance?

```
<Response>
 <T>
  <Item A="..." B="..." C="..." ... />
  <Item A="..." B="..." C="..." ... />
  <Item A="..." B="..." C="..." ... />
  ...
 </T>
</Response>
```

code:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(mContext.getAssets().open("t.xml"));
Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8");
...
Persister serializer = new Persister();
respT = serializer.read(RespT.class, decoder, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [Vtd-Xml](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/), it faster than most parsers.

Comment: After using Vtd-Xml (with XPath) I've got the result in 1.5 sec for this xml file.
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

If the xml's structure is simple and don't change in time - you have the same tags and the tree is simple, you may build your own parser.